# Hide Shipping method

Tags: checkout, shipping

I want to hide a shipping method based on customer region and product attribute (deliver_today - Yes/No product attribute).

If the Customer Shipping Region is a certain region and all the cart items have `deliver_today` attribute `Yes` then display all the Shipping Methods, but if the 
Customer Shipping Region is a certain region but not all the cart items have deliver_today attribute Yes then display all the shipping methods except the `flatrate_flatrate`.

Below is my available.phtml and I added the necessary if else combinations but not working. Can anyone help?

```
<?php $_shippingRateGroups = $this->getShippingRates(); ?>
<?php $customerRegion = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion(); ?>
<?php if (!$_shippingRateGroups): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>

    <?php 
        $customerRegion = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        $deliverToday = true;
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $product = $productModel->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            if($product->getData('deliver_today')){
                $deliverToday = false;
            }else{
                $deliverToday = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    ?>

    <dl class="sp-methods">
    <?php $shippingCodePrice = array(); ?>
    <?php $_sole = count($_shippingRateGroups) == 1; foreach ($_shippingRateGroups as $code => $_rates): ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCarrierName($code)) ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul class="designota-carriers">
            <?php $_sole = $_sole && count($_rates) == 1; foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>
                <?php $shippingCodePrice[] = "'".$_rate->getCode()."':".(float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>
                <?php
    if($customerRegion == 'Sample Customer Region'){
        if($_rate->getCode() == 'flatrate_flatrate' && $deliverToday == false) {
                $deliverToday = ' no-display';
        } else if ($_rate->getCode() == 'flatrate_flatrate' && $deliverToday == true){
                $deliverToday = '';
        } else {
                $deliverToday = '';
        }
    } else {
        $deliverToday = ' no-display';
    }
                ?>
    <li class="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?><?php echo $deliverToday; ?>">
       <?php if ($_rate->getErrorMessage()): ?>
        <ul class="messages"><li class="error-msg"><ul><li><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rate->getErrorMessage()) ?></li></ul></li></ul>
       <?php else: ?>
            <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
            <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
            <?php else: ?>
            <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>

            <?php if ($_rate->getCode() === $this->getAddressShippingMethod()): ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                    lastPrice = <?php echo (float)$_rate->getPrice(); ?>;
                //]]>
            </script>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <label for="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>">
            <span class="designota-carrier-logos s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"></span>
            <?php $_excl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), $this->helper('tax')->displayShippingPriceIncludingTax()); ?>
            <?php $_incl = $this->getShippingPrice($_rate->getPrice(), true); ?>
            <?php echo $_excl; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayShippingBothPrices() && $_incl != $_excl): ?>
                (<?php echo $this->__('Incl. Tax'); ?> <?php echo $_incl; ?>)
            <?php endif; ?>
            </label>
       <?php endif ?>
    </li>
            <?php //} ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try free version of [Owebia Shipping](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html)? It let you add many conditions to shipping methods.